# Backward Time Flow?

Tags: experimental-physics, time, entropy, arrow-of-time

Physicists say that time is moving foward because entropy always increases. But have physicists considered that we might be mistaken? Since there is no ultimate reference frame, it could be possible that we are in fact moving backwards in time, that entropy in reality decreases, that causality is just an illusion, that the Big Bang was actually the end of the universe and that from total disorder (predicted heat death of the universe) naturally comes order (the universe at $t=0$). I know it seems ridiculous that people begin dead, then assemble themselves into living being, live their life backwards, enter their mother's uterus and decompose back into sperms but I don't see any physical law that makes it impossible to happen. Maybe time doesn't move at all or it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: See "Cryptozoic" by Brian Aldiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People defined time as a variable going forward long before entropy was defined.

Biological/consciousness time, which you also discuss, forced the concept of time and a way /unit to measure it, as cultivation and buildings forced a concept of space and units to measure it. The celestial clock of sun moon and planets was used even by primitive people. Nobody in tribal history and then recorded history saw the sun going backwards or the moon and the planets.

Then physics became the science we now know, i.e. it started using mathematical models to fit observations which models were validated by observations and predictions for new behaviors of data.

Physical laws become written in mathematics ( not stone) by the existence of these mathematical formulations and are called laws because they have never been falsified to force new mathematical models.

[Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) is a variable emerging from thermodynamics as its second law, that it always stays the same or increases in the progress of the time variable ( those orbits of the moon and planets). When atomic physics was understood [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28statistical_thermodynamics%29) became defined as a matter of probabilities .

Before the editing by the moderator you had asked:

> but I don't see any physical law that makes it impossible to happen. Maybe time doesn't move at all or it doesn't exist at all.

Meaning can a decrease in entropy happen? It  can happen, but it is very very improbable as there are zillions of microsystem for any bulk matter on which entropy can be defined. And this will be only for the reversal of the time concept for one bit out of the enormous content of matter in the universe. No consistent reversal has a probability of reversing the entropic definition of time.

Therefore there cannot be backward time flow within the framework of physics we have now. The rest is imagination belonging to science fiction or religion/metaphysics.

Answer (score -3):

Time is perceived threw moving objects, changes and things transitioning from order to disorder (positive entropy). But time itself is a dimensional axis much like length, height and width. "but as far as the discussion on entropy" it is dynamically highly improbable and could mean harnessing all the energy in the universe in order to reverse it. "but then, what would be the difference".

Comment: This is philosophical crap with no basis in science.

Comment: Brandon Enright-obviously any inkling of philosophy is looked down on when it comes to this site! As much as I love physics, its nothing but pure lifeless concentrated rigor without the conditioning of philosophical reasoning, unequipped to effectively tackle the inquiries which originally belong  philosophy.

Comment: A physics questions site isn't the right place to debate the need for philosophy.  Stick to the science.